# Why does each_cons yield arrays instead of multiple values?

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerator

I just wanted to apply a binary operation to consecutive elements in an array, e.g.:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each_cons(2).map { |a, b| a.quo(b) }
#=> [(1/2), (2/3), (3/4)]
```

This is a contrived example, the operation doesn't really matter.

I was surprised, that I couldn't just write:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each_cons(2).map(&:quo)
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `quo' for [1, 2]:Array
```

This is because `each_cons` doesn't yield multiple values, but an array containing the values.

It works like this:

```
def each_cons_arrays
  return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?
  yield [1, 2]
  yield [2, 3]
  yield [3, 4]
end

each_cons_arrays.map(&:quo)
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `quo' for [1, 2]:Array
```

And I was hoping for:

```
def each_cons_values
  return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?
  yield 1, 2
  yield 2, 3
  yield 3, 4
end

each_cons_values.map(&:quo)
#=> [(1/2), (2/3), (3/4)]
```

What's the rationale behind this? Why could it be preferable to always have an array?

And by the way, `with_index` on the other hand does yield multiple values:

```
[1, 1, 1].each.with_index(2).map(&:quo)
#=> [(1/2), (1/3), (1/4)]
```

Comment: What is expectation if you were doing `each_cons(3)` ?  What you are asking may be apt only for `each_cons(2)`.

Comment: @WandMaker that it yields 3 values. Of course, this wouldn't work with `quo`, because it only takes 1 argument.

Comment: Besides, I think `each_cons(2)` is a _very_ common case.

Comment: I think you have to monkey patch `Enumerable` to add a method to provide that behaviour,  whether its needed by larger group of programmers is difficult to ascertain.

Comment: At a guess because it's easier for it (both implementation wise and as a user) to be consistent and always yield an array versus sometimes yield an array and sometimes yield individual elements.

Comment: @WandMaker is the current behavior needed? To put it another way: are there typical use-cases where a yielded array is preferable / more manageable?

Comment: @FrederickCheung that's right, but then again, `with_object` and `with_index` are inconsistent. Furthermore, there is `Enumerable#each_entry` which can be used to convert multiple values to an array, but it doesn't work the other way round.

Comment: That's not what I meant. With_index, with_object always yield 2 values whereas each_cons yields a varying number.  For small values of n it probably would be nice for each_cons(n) to yield values for your use case but for larger values of n or of uses arrays would be better

Comment: I thought that you had a feature request/bug report in Ruby core, but I cannot find it.

Comment: @sawa I've filed a [bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12466) now, but I'm not quite sure if this actually is a bug.

Comment: @Stefan I think it is a feature, but an inconsistent feature (so it can be considered a design error). I might have had wrong memory. Maybe you had asked a similar question on SO, not in Ruby core.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it helps to think of multiple values in ruby as an array.

It think of it at as

```
[1,2,3].each_cons(2) do |iter|
  a,b = iter
  do_stuff(a,b)
end
```

If you want to do it like that, I'd add the `quo` method to a custom class, and do

```
class Foobar
  def initialize(a,b)
    @a = a
    @b = b
  end

  def quo
    do_stuff
  end
end

[1,2,3]
  .each_cons(2)
  .map { |a,b| Foobar.new(a,b) }
  .map(:quo)
```

Would that work for your usecase?

Comment: Your first example only works that way, because `each_cons` yields arrays. But there is a difference between yielding multiple values and yielding an array containing these values. For example, `each_with_index` _does_ yield multiple values and therefore, `%w(a b c).each_with_index.map { |e| e }` returns `["a", "b", "c"]`, not `[["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2]]`